# AttributeError: 'DataTransferServiceClient' object has no attribute 'project_transfer_config_path'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Got the following code:

```
import time
from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1

def runQuery (parent, requested_run_time):
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()
    projectid = '[enter your projectId here]' # Enter your projectID here
    transferid = '[enter your transferId here]'  # Enter your transferId here
    parent = client.project_transfer_config_path(projectid, transferid)
    start_time = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.Timestamp(seconds=int(time.time() + 10))
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(parent, requested_run_time=start_time)
    print(response)
```

We used it in few different projects and cases and everything works fine. Today I deployed another function using this code and keep getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataTransferServiceClient' object has no attribute
> 'project_transfer_config_path'

What am I missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a newer version (2.0.0 or 2.1.0) of the `google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer` client library. In these versions, [most utility methods have been removed](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/UPGRADING.html#removed-utility-methods), one of them being `project_transfer_config_path`.

You can use the method [`transfer_config_path`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/bigquery_datatransfer_v1/services.html#google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.services.data_transfer_service.DataTransferServiceClient.transfer_config_path) of the client to achieve the same result.

I would strongly suggest that you study the [Migration Guide to 2.0.0](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/UPGRADING.html#migration-guide) as there might be other changes that you need to make too.

In case you are using version 2.0.0 and not 2.1.0, I would recommend upgrading to the latest since there are breaking changes between them, for example the import paths that were [changed in 2.0.0](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/UPGRADING.html#version-2-0-0) have been reverted in 2.1.0.